# V8JS Timezone Test Fails

Tags: javascript, php, v8, v8js

I'm trying to install V8JS but a timezone test is failing. This test:
https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/php7/tests/timezones.phpt

I followed these instructions https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/php7/README.Linux.md

The issue the test has is that the Date printed is wrong:

```
================================================================================
001+ string(15) "Europe/Helsinki"
002+ Thu Mar 20 2014 11:03:24 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
003+ string(16) "America/New_York"
004+ Thu Mar 20 2014 11:03:24 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
005+ string(15) "Europe/Helsinki"
006+ Thu Mar 20 2014 11:03:24 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
001- Thu Mar 20 2014 11:03:24 GMT+0200 (EET)
002- Thu Mar 20 2014 05:03:24 GMT-0400 (EDT)
003- Thu Mar 20 2014 11:03:24 GMT+0200 (EET)
================================================================================
```

The upper 6 Lines are the ACTUAL output. I added a var_dump(getenv('TZ')); to make sure that the timezone is getting changed. The last 3 lines are the expected output. As you can see everything is GMT+0200 which is wrong, only 2 should be +0200

I've checked my php.ini and remove any timezone settings, this did not help at all sadly. Same issue.

Has anyone ever run into something similar? Or Does anyone have an Idea?
I've tried just using V8JS as is, but it crashes sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled a third version of V8 (6.5.143) and this fixed the problem. Not sure why, but atleast the test works now.